# Using Text::sprintf with Text::script

Tags: joomla-4.x, joomla-5.x

I have a language string which need be used with sprintf :

```
COM_COMPONENT_UPLOADED_LABEL_ERROR_REACHED_MAX_NUMBER_FILES = "You have reached the maximum number of files allowed (maximum allowed are %d files)"
```

This string is used in javascript part so how to use Text::sprintf with Text::script ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in function in Joomla and JS has no equivalent of `sprintf()`. You have to write your own. It may be impractical to try mimic PHP in JS so instead you could write a simplified version for your use case. For example, Media component has this code which just replaces most commonly used `%s` and `%d` specifiers:

```
const Translate = {
    // Translate from Joomla text
    translate: (key) => Joomla.Text._(key, key),
    sprintf: (string, ...args) => {
      const newString = Translate.translate(string);
      let i = 0;
      return newString.replace(/%((%)|s|d)/g, (m) => {
        let val = args[i];

        if (m === '%d') {
          val = parseFloat(val);
          if (Number.isNaN(val)) {
            val = 0;
          }
        }
        i += 1;
        return val;
      });
    }
}
```